# Windows Forms: Windows label doesn't render

Tags: c#, winforms

Similar to

```
MessageBox.Show("Test", "Test")
```

I have made a ProgressWindow, which is shown before a long-running action, and hidden thereafter:

```
ProgressWindow.Show("Test","Test")
Thread.Sleep(20000);
ProgressWindow.Hide();
```

using the following code:

```
class ProgressWindow : Form
{
    private Label label1;

    private static ProgressWindow window;

    internal static void Show(string Message, string Caption)
    {
        window = new ProgressWindow(Message, Caption);
        window.Show();
    }

    internal new static void Hide()
    {
        (ProgressWindow.window as Control).Hide();
    }

    private ProgressWindow(string Message, string Caption)
    {
        InitializeComponent(Message, Caption);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent(string Message, string Caption)
    {
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 40);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 120);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = Message;
        // 
        // ProgressWindow
        // 
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 200);
        this.ShowIcon = false;
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.ControlBox = false;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Name = "ProgressWindow";
        this.Text = Caption;
        this.TopMost = true;
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
}
```

The problem now is that my progress window is shown, but in the position of the label, there is a white box only, and no text. Furthermore, if I try to click the window, the title changes from "Test" to "Test (not responding...)".

Why is that, and how would I change that?

I suspected an issue with thread blocking (but why? shouldn't the label be rendered?) and tried

```
internal static void Show(string Message, string Caption)
{
    window = new ProgressWindow(Message, Caption);
    new Thread(t => {
        window.Show();
    }).Start();
}
```

but this doesn't show the ProgressWindow form at all.

Comment: Im guessing because your long running process is running on the UI thread.

Comment: Thats because your `Thread.Sleep(..)` blocks the current thread. The thread is also responsible for updating the UI. You should move the workitems to a separate thread, instead of displaying the progresswindow on another thread.

Comment: This is a multidupe, but I wouldn't know which one to close it as a dupe of.  You must understand that the UI thread must be free to update the UI, and if you *block the UI thread* by, for example, sleeping the bugger, it can't do its job.  The subject of multithreading in a windows application is covered all over the bloody place.  I'd suggest you restrain your searches to the past year, so you won't use any of the older patterns, such as using a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: (reads first answer) awwww jeeeeez....

Comment: Use ProgressWindow.Update().  Keeps you having to learn threading for a while, probably best.

Comment: @HansPassant If you want, you can make that an answer I can accept :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem is due to thread blocking. When `Thread.Sleep()` is called, the current thread is doing nothing, which means that no Windows messages are processed. This prevents your progress dialog from completely displaying its UI.

I'm not exactly sure why calling the `Show()` method on a background thread doesn't work, but I believe that WinForms requires the UI thread to be a Single Threaded Apartment, and by default threads are Multi-Threaded Apartment.

To implement this properly, I would suggested using the [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. It automatically creates a background thread to perform the long running work on, and will fire an even once the work completes. You can use it something like this:

```
ProgressWindow.Show("Test","Test");

var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += (sender, args) => {
    // perform your long running task here, this is a background thread
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
};
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) => {
    // update the UI here, this is running on the UI thread
    ProgressWindow.Hide();
}
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Note that `RunWorkerAsync()` will return right away, so your UI will need to handle the fact that the user can interact with the UI before the background task has finished.